# Errors thrown from wcf service when inferring a type from an entity model

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

Had something interesting happen and wonder if anyone knows a good reason for it to be so.  I am developing line of business applications in .NET and Silverlight that access database information of various types.

To achieve this I have made use of Entity Framework and WCF services which I am hosting on a seperate site on our intranet.  At one point last week I had published the service which would return a List of items of an inferred type (defined by the table in my Entity Data Model).

Long story short, I was banging my head against a wall trying to solve a NotFound error that was being returned by the server.  Turns out all I had to do was write a class and assemble the list manually, so the problem is solved...but I still wonder.

Why does a wcf service not function properly if the type is determined by the table?
Would this be related to read only status? or a lack of ident key?

Answer (score 0):

You probably encountered a circular reference, caused by navigation properties on your model.

Enable [WCF tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) to see the real error.

Comment: ah, that may explain it...not sure if I really want to recreate the issue to test it out tho:P  Not after I found a safe solution.  In the end it was really solved by a decision to not be lazy. Rather than just send all the information (not much really), I'll be delivering only that which is necessary.